# Laravel - First Time User

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When the user logged in for the first time via email and password given to the user manually. They need to be forced to enter a new password (password and confirmed password - only two fields).

I have created a middleware:

```
class FirstTimeLogin
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if ($request->user()->first_time_login) {
            return redirect()->route('setup-password');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

In `Kernel.php` I have added  `\App\Http\Middleware\FirstTimeLogin::class` in the `$middlewareGroups` array: eg:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\FirstTimeLogin::class
    ]
];
```

web.php route look like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

    Route::get('/password/setup-password', 'Auth\SetupPasswordController@resetPasswordFirstTime')->name('setup-password');
    Route::post('/password/setup-password', 'Auth\SetupPasswordController@updatePassword');

});
```

Problem is it keep redirecting many times on the browser, which caused `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error on the browser. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just applied the new middleware to all the web routes, so when user is redirected to `->route('setup-password')` middleware kicks in again so you have infinite redirects

One way to fix this is to create an exclusion for those 2 routes that are used for password setup

Make sure you give second route a name, something like `setup-password-post`

And then change your middleware for code:

```
if ($request->user()->first_time_login) {
    if (!in_array(Route::currentRouteName(), ['setup-password', 'setup-password-post'])) {
        return redirect()->route('setup-password');
    }
}
```

Comment: Will that solve it? When user submit POST to update the password, it will be redirected to a `'Auth\SetupPasswordController@updatePassword'`  controller.

Comment: Would you personally put new middleware to all the web routes?

Comment: You submitting the form to the named route and before request is getting passed to `SetupPasswordController@updatePassword` middleware will kick in and name check should not initiate the redirect

Comment: I would not, better change login function to check for `->first_time_login` and initiate the redirect right after it confirms user credentials

Comment: Problem with login function approach you are suggestion, that user might ignore it and go to different page. middleware will force to redirect it.

Comment: User is not gonna be able to do it if you add code logic for redirect to the function that is responsible of logging user in in `Auth\LoginController`

Comment: Redirect in the function, I am assuming the user will not be logged in and they will have to enter the email and current password again and including new password?

Comment: Oh I see you want to not allow them do anything before they change their password after the first login, than yes you need a middleware like you originally designed

Comment: $is_setup_route = Route::is('setup*');

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to put a check in to make sure the current route isn't `setup-password`.

Try changing your if statement to something like:

```
if ($request->user()->first_time_login && !$request->is('setup-password')) {
```